# Lemma 1 - Banach-Mazur Game - Dan Ma's topology Blog

Tags: general-topology

I have been given a presentation for a course based on this particular [post](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/06/08/the-banach-mazur-game/) in Dan Ma's topology blog. The post itself is very clear and educational, but there is one proof that I'm not sure why it is complete.

Lemma 1 has a rather standard application of Zorn's lemma, but I feel that I'm missing something in the second paragraph of the proof.

Lemma 1: Let $X$ be a space, Let $O \subset X$ be a nonempty open set. Let $\tau$ be the set of all nonempty open subsets of $O$. Let $f: \tau \longrightarrow \tau$ be a function such that for each $V \in \tau$, $f(V) \subset V$. Then, there exists a disjoint collection $\mathcal{U}$ consisting of elements of $f(\tau)$ such that $\bigcup \mathcal{U}$ is dense in $O$.

The proof begins by explaining the trivial case of $O$ having just one point, then if I understand correctly everything holds in a rather obvious way, namely: the property of $f$ gives me the same set as an image and clearly this is dense in $O$.

Then, we assume $O$ has two points and the author shows that $\mathcal{P}$ (the set of all collections $\mathcal{F}$ such that $\mathcal{F}$ is a disjoint collection of elements of $f(\tau)$) is non-empty. For this, two *disjoint* open subsets of $O$ are taken based on the assumption that $O$ has at least two points.

Why must these subsets be disjoint? Isn't the author assuming anything in addition?

I underestand that by applying $f$ later those sets become exactly of the form of an element of $\mathcal{P}$ which is the goal of that particular part of the proof. I thought we could possibly assume they are disjoint and otherwise apply $f$ again and again until they are but no assumption really guarantees this process would stop.

Comment: At the end of the introductrory section of the post you linked to, the author states: "All topological spaces are assumed to be at least Hausdorff."

Comment: Oh, I feel so silly not having noticed that. The solution is rather nice so at least I know now we don't need that assumption at all

Answer (score 2):

You are correct: unless the author is assuming that $X$ is Hausdorff, $O$ need not contain two disjoint non-empty open sets. However, the argument can easily be patched. If $O$ does not contain two disjoint non-empty open sets, let $\mathscr{U}=\{\tau(O)\}$; every non-empty open subset of $O$ meets $\tau(O)$, so $\bigcup\mathscr{U}=\tau(O)$ is dense in $O$, and we’re done right away.

Comment: Thank you! I was going in circles trying to force something to be true when in fact it was missing something. Very elegant patch!

Comment: @Deborah: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 0):

In the introduction, before the heading Banach-Mazur Game, he says that all spaces are assumed to be Hausdorff.

And then if $O$ has at least two points, say $p \neq q$, we can find disjoint open  sets $U_p$ and $U_q$ around them and then $\{U_p \cap O, U_q \cap O\}$ is a starting point, one of the members of your poset of disjoint open subfamilies of $O$ etc.